# Advanced SQL select to get same column value with different heade name

Tags: mysql

I am trying to create a select query from a table T1 that has four columns which looks like below

- File_name
- agnt_name
- agnt_lot_num
- agnt_serial_num

My goal is to get a select output table that has column names as synoynym , like below

File_name, 'UDAV', 'Hemat', 'CCI'

The challenging condition I have is:

```
UDAV - SELECT agnt_serial_num FROM T1 WHERE agnt_name ='UV inhibitor'
Hemat - SELECT agnt_serial_num FROM T1 WHERE agnt_name ='hematoxylin'
CCI - SELECT concat(agnt_serial_num,'_',agnt_lot_num) FROM T1 WHERE agnt_name ='Carbon Morpher'
```

Each of these 'agnt_name(s)' are unique for a file_name. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Can you edit your question with samples of your source data as well as the desired results?

Comment: you want to turn the CONTENTS of those fields in any particular record into the names of the columns returned by the select query?

Comment: pretty difficult to understand this question.  you may be asking about a PIVOT table, or you may want column alias, or you may need to select from the same table 3 times for values in each column - but you have not specified how these might link via a key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i'm going to guess:

```
select a.file_name
, a.sn as 'UDAV'
, b.sn as 'Hemat'
, c.sn as 'CCI'
from 
( SELECT agnt_serial_num sn FROM T1 WHERE agnt_name ='UV inhibitor' ) a
,( SELECT agnt_serial_num sn FROM T1 WHERE agnt_name ='hematoxylin' )b
,( SELECT concat(agnt_serial_num,'_',agnt_lot_num) sn FROM T1 WHERE agnt_name ='Carbon Morpher' ) c
where a.file_name = b.file_name
and b.file_name = c.file_name
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there [What you looking for?](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp)

Maybe i miss understood your demand